# Windows UWP - I am trying to create a unit test in VS 2017 that needs to access the local user

Tags: c#, unit-testing, authentication, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to create a unit test in Visual Studio 2017 that needs to get the logged in user name. I have the permissions in my Unit Test project to allow access to user account information. I copied the permissions exactly from my production App. My production apps populates the username filed but the Unit Test app returns a blank user. I never get the popup that confirms that I want to allow access to user account information in my Unit Test.

```
var users = await User.FindAllAsync();
if (users != null)
{
// get users that match our list of interest
var current = users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AuthenticationStatus == UserAuthenticationStatus.LocallyAuthenticated && x.Type == UserType.LocalUser);
// Verify there is at least on user before getting info.
if (current != null)
{
var data = await current.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.DomainName);
if (data != null)
   username = data.ToString();
}
}
```

Comment: If your unit test depends on *anything* outside then it's not really a unit test.

Comment: What does that mean? I can't test anything until I get the logged in user name

Comment: It means you don't have a unit test. Unit tests are for testing discrete pieces of code with no outside dependencies, or fake/mocked outside dependencies. Their results should always be the same. Stop calling it a unit test, because it's not one if it depends on the logged in username.